# 'Error 424 Object required' while running a macro that selects a dynamic column

Tags: excel, vba

I wanted to record a macro that select's the entire column by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd> but that's not possible without using VBA.

This is my code:

```
Sub updatestrial()

    Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Select.AdvancedFilter            Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range( _
    "H5"), Unique:=True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to select in VBA

```
Sub updatestrial()

Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlDown)).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range("H5"), Unique:=True

 End Sub
```

But this will only work if there are no blanks within your data, and you haven't explicitly identified the sheet so it will only work with the currently activesheet. If you want all the data in column A of a sheet called "Sheet1" then a better solution would be

```
 Sub updatestrial()
 Dim r as Range
 Dim ws as worksheet
 Set ws  = worksheets("Sheet1")
 Set r = ws.range(ws.range("A1"),ws.cells(ws.rows.count,1).end(xlup))
  r.advancedfilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=ws.Range("H5"), Unique:=True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an unnecessary `.Select` in there. Try:

```
Sub UpdatesTrial()
    Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlDown)).AdvancedFilter _
        Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CopyToRange:=Range("H5"), _
        Unique:=True
End Sub
```